# Можно ли где то установить модуль turtle для Python 3.8. У меня была повреждена эта библиотека

Tags: python

Моя библиотека turtle была повреждена. Хочу узнать , как ее установить. Или придется переустанавливать питон? Если что версия 3.8

Comment: Почему бы и не переустановить

Comment: У меня виндовс 7 и на нем очень сложно переустанавливать. Второй раз может и не установиться(

Comment: Установка питона на любых версиях винды принципиально никак не менялась за последние 15 лет

Comment: интересно послушать в чем же заключается сложность переустановки конкретно на вин7?

Comment: То есть нигде больше установить черепашку нельзя?

Comment: у меня такой же виндовс 7 и все там легко переустанавливается

Answer (score 0):

открываешь cmd, вводишь по очереди:

```
pip uninstall PythonTurtle
pip install PythonTurtle
```

если я конечно правильно понял, что за "черепашку" ты имеешь в виду

Comment: `PythonTurtle` - это не стандартный `turtle`.

Comment: а в python есть стандартная библиотека turtle?.. век живи, век учись, чё сказать